# how to solve r error :could not find function "%||%"

Tags: r, syntax

I keep getting the following error - could not find function `%||%`.  I would like to know what r  `library()` supports `%||%` and what this function is doing.

Thanks 
Leanne

Comment: i mostly see it defined as `\`%||%\` <- function(x, y) if (is.null(x)) y else x`, fairly common in many packages as an internal utility function (eg, `ggplot2:::\`%||%\``), so it's hard to say where you are getting the error from unless you share your code

Comment: It could mean anything depending on who defined it. Function names aren't unique across all R packages. You would need to provide more context to have a chance at guessing what the code you are looking at is meant to do.

Comment: `?'%||%'` on my R points me to two packages: __rlang__ and __purrr__

Comment: A handy function to find unknown functions (assuming you have the package installed, you just don't know where to find it): `getAnywhere("%||%)`

Comment: `getAnywhere` will work for packages that are loaded, but in a fresh r session or if the namespace isn't loaded, you won't get any results

Comment: Thanks everyone! rlang did the trick and I will definitely use that getAnywhere() in the future!!